# Not able to build Postgres docker file with pg_strom

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, gpu, nvidia

I am trying to build a Postgres image in docker with pg_strom extension so that I can use GPU based query acceleration in engine, I have a NVidia Xavier device with GPU integrated, but following Docker file is not able to build Postgres with pg_strom extension.

```
FROM postgres:latest

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    git \
    pgxnclient \
    postgresql-server-dev-13

# Clone and build pg_strom
RUN git clone https://github.com/pg-strom/devel.git /pg_strom
WORKDIR /pg_strom
RUN make && make install

# Clean up
RUN rm -rf /pg_strom

# Set environment variables (optional)
ENV PG_STROM_ENABLED=on

# Expose PostgreSQL port
EXPOSE 5432
```

The **docker-compose.prod.yml** content is following

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  database:
    container_name: database-gpu
    networks:
      - mlbridge
    build:
      context: ./database
    runtime: nvidia
    volumes:
      - ./:/imports
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    env_file:
      - ./.env.prod.db
    restart: always
```

The error log is following

```
sd@sd-desktop:~/codebase/app$ sudo docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml build database
[+] Building 300.4s (8/9)
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 473B                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/postgres:latest                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => CACHED [1/6] FROM docker.io/library/postgres:latest                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => [2/6] RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y     build-essential     git     pgxnclient     postgresql-server-dev-13                                                                                  267.3s
 => [3/6] RUN git clone https://github.com/pg-strom/devel.git /pg_strom                                                                                                                                      31.4s
 => [4/6] WORKDIR /pg_strom                                                                                                                                                                                   0.1s
 => ERROR [5/6] RUN make && make install                                                                                                                                                                      1.4s
------
 > [5/6] RUN make && make install:
#0 0.988 git archive --format=tar.gz \
#0 0.988             --prefix=pg_strom-5.0beta/ \
#0 0.988             -o pg_strom-5.0beta.tar.gz f7fedc8bae6e8021c11a5ad8ac66136fc3d474e1 \
#0 0.988             LICENSE Makefile Makefile.common \
#0 0.988             src arrow-tools test/ssbm
#0 1.296 /bin/sh: 1: rpmbuild: not found
#0 1.301 /bin/sh: 1: rpmbuild: not found
#0 1.303 /bin/sh: 1: rpmbuild: not found
#0 1.304 /bin/sh: 1: rpmbuild: not found
#0 1.305 cp -f pg_strom-5.0beta.tar.gz  || exit 1
#0 1.313 cp: missing destination file operand after 'pg_strom-5.0beta.tar.gz'
#0 1.313 Try 'cp --help' for more information.
#0 1.313 make: *** [Makefile:26: rpm-pg_strom] Error 1
------
failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c make && make install]: exit code: 2
sd@sd-desktop:~/codebase/app$
```

What do I need to change in the file to build successfully?

Comment: `is not able` - maybe some details would let people help you? An error message or anything like that?

Comment: @RichardHuxton i added the build logs and docker-compose file content

Comment: First try to build the extension without docker, on a local installation. Read the documentation. Once that works, add the additional layer of a Docker image.

Comment: I think it's not as easy as you think. See [Docs](https://heterodb.github.io/pg-strom/install/#postgresql-installation)